# Why does iCloud Drive take up almost 2 GB of my iPhone storage?

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, storage

On my iPhone (iOS 14.1), in Settings > General > iPhone Storage, iCloud Drive is fifth in the list of storage space, at 1.84 GB. When I tap on it, it just tells me that "Documents & Data" are using 1.84 GB, with no further breakdown.

I'm a bit confused, as I hardly use iCloud Drive. When I look at the iCloud Drive folder on my Mac (macOS Catalina, 10.15.7), I've got 11 top-level folders; four are empty, and the biggest is listed as 8.7 MB. I've got one top-level file, a 1.4 MB PDF file.

Where is the 1.84 GB listed on iOS coming from?

Comment: This might include 3rd party applications that use iCloud Drive to store files, even if they don't make this clear to you.

Comment: @EzekielElin: can 3rd-party applications store files in iCloud Drive without creating a folder named after that application then? I have several 3rd-party application folders in iCloud Drive. Are there files in iCloud Drive that I can't see in the Files app on iOS, or in the Finder on macOS?

Comment: Yes, in general I believe they can